# ¿Cómo poner una imagen a lado de un texto de cabecera en HTML?

Tags: html, web

Quisiera saber como el texto de una etiqueta h1, se ponga en la misma linea de una imagen y los dos aparezcan en el mismo nivel.

-Me seria muy util gracias!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes intentar utilizar estilos ya sea inline o usando clases css.
Para poner elementos en la misma linea se utiliza la propiedad

```
display: inline-block;
```

Lo puedes agregar tanto a tu imagen como al h1 con la propiedad style

```
<h1 style="display: inline-block"></h1>
```

O usar una clase de css

```
[css]
.inline {
     display: inline-block;
 }

[Html]
<h1 class="inline"></h1>
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Usa un estilo **css** y utiliza la propiedad `display:inline-block` aquí un ejemplo:

```css
h2,img{
display:inline-block;
}

/*solo demostrativo*/
#nivel{
background-color:yellow;
}
#otro{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nivel">
   <h2>Texto de encabezado</h2>
   <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png">
</div>
<div id="otro">
  otro nivel
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias! Ya aprendi algo nuevo

Answer (score -3):

```
<h1><img src=""></img>  Welcome </h1>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor cuando vayas a responder una pregunta debes dar una explicación de lo que hiciste no simplemente poner el código, debes ser consciente que estamos ayudando a que otras personas puedan comprender las respuestas y aprender. Saludos!